# Writing two sentences in a short way

Tags: grammar

I'm not an English native speaker. I'm trying to translate an abstract of a scientific work to English.

The problem in the work has **zero Neumann condition for the angle displacement**. The problem also has **zero Neumann condition for the longitudinal displacement**.

I'd like to know how to write these informations in a short way. However, I dont know how the grammar works in this case. Is the sentence below correct?

> The problem has zero Neumann conditions for the angle and
>   longitudinal displacements.

Some specific doubts: Should I insert "for the" or "the" before "longitudinal"? Should I write "displacement" after "angle"  and use singular at the end?

Thanks.

Comment: Would "angular displacement" be possible? Sounds more natural and in sync with "longitudinal". But if it's a technical term....

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is grammatically correct. There are two changes you should consider:

1. EDIT: Oops! Per Tetsujin's comment, "Zero Neumann condition" is apparently correct mathematical jargon. I found an example of your usage on Google (Remark 1.9 [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1306.4260)). You could also say "for both the angle and longitudinal displacements".
2. Change "The problem" to "This problem". Only do this if you've already mentioned the problem.

Comment: a 'zero Neumann condition' is a specific; it's not the same as not having a condition, it has one, the result is zero.

Comment: "This problem" is fine for an abstract, even when it's explained *afterwards* .

Comment: @Tetsujin: Thank you for the correction. I've updated my answer.